# JQuery condition for all inputs

Tags: jquery

I want create a jquery function to change a css input attribute if value change.
The problem: I want a generic function not repeat the same code for all diferents inputs

My code (repeat jquery code):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

            var initinputvalue1 = $("#input1").val();
            $("#input1").change(function(){
                if ( $("#input1").val() !== initinputvalue1 ) {
                    $("#input1").css("border-color", "rgb(255, 144, 0)");
                }
            });
            var initinputvalue2 = $("#input2").val();
            $("#input2").change(function(){
                if ( $("#input2").val() !== initinputvalue2 ) {
                    $("#input2").css("border-color", "rgb(255, 144, 0)");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2"/
```

Is possible something like that?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        var initinputvalue = $(":input").val();
            $(":input").change(function(){
                if ( $(":input").val() != initinputvalue ) {
                    $(":input").css("border-color", "blue");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<label for="input1">Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2"/>
    <br><br>
```

It does not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the same logic work for multiple elements put a common class on them and then select by that class. You can then use the `this` keyword, or the `target` property of the event, to reference the element which raised the event inside the handler.

In addition, note that your code can be simplified. For the `change` event to fire the value of the element must have changed, therefore your `if` condition is redundant and can be removed. Try this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery($ => {
    $(".input").on('change', function() {
      $(this).css("border-color", "rgb(255, 144, 0)");
    });
    
    // alternative:
    // $('.input').on('change', e => $(e.target).css("border-color", "rgb(255, 144, 0)"));
  });
</script>
<label for="input1">Input 1</label>
<input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" class="input" />
<br><br>
<label for="input2">Input 2</label>
<input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" class="input" />
```